# Swift: How to encode object, only different properties by compare with the original object

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I would like to send an object to my server in body. But in the encoded function I would like to compare it first to another object of the same type and only encode the properties which are different,

Without having to compare each property like this:

```
        if firstName != objectToCompare.firstName {
            try container.encodeIfPresent(firstName, forKey: .firstName)
        }

        if lastName != objectToCompare.lastName {
            try container.encodeIfPresent(lastName, forKey: .lastName)
        }
```

Because I have big objects, and having to write a lot of times the condition for each property is long and not reusable because I want to implement this system for all my objects.

So I'm looking for an extension of `Encodable` to compare properties

Comment: You'll just have to write out that code. You can use key paths to make it a little neater but there's no magic bullet; you're going to have to list all the properties you want to compare.

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe you could use property wrappers (Swift 5.1) for this

Comment: Can you explain what is your idea with the property wrapper?

Comment: I was just thinking that it could be related somehow to this: https://github.com/marksands/BetterCodable - which does something similar, but the other way round.